# mp3 audio + background.jpg = result.mp4 in ffmpeg

Tags: video, youtube, ffmpeg

having problem converting video into mp4 to upload on youtube.

I have converted into avi format with below command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i background.jpg -i deepmix.mp3 -c:a copy result.avi
```

but when i upload this to youtube it is in "processing state"(0%). as per this https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/71674?hl=en I waited 8 hours but no luck.

also tried converting avi to mp4 with below command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ac 2 out.mp4
```

no luck. not able to play out.mp4 in vlc.(audio is playing no video) but when i upload this video to youtube it was in "processing state"(95%).

also tried :

```
ffmpeg  -i result.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 out.mp4
```

Still in "processing state"(95%) when i upload to youtube.

**how do i directly convert into mp4 720hd video with one audio(mp3) and one image (jpg) ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably getting a single frame of video, using this instead:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.jpg -i deepmix.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
```

tells ffmpeg to loop the image (-loop) as well as stopping at the end of the audio (-shortest)